# How to read line by line in node.js synchronously?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In node.js, I want to be able to read line by line synchronously (not read the whole file), and also be able to stop reading after some amount of lines.

I saw this https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html but they don't explain how to do it synchronously. I also tried this

https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader

```
lineReader.eachLine('big_file.txt', function(line, last) {
  console.log(line);

  if (last) {
    return false; // stop reading
  }
});
console.log("test");
```

but `test` prints before the file gets read, which they say is synchronous. but it looks like it's not.

I want the test print to appear after the lines get printed.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: `readline` is for efficient and asynchronous processing. If you insist on blocking, you can use [`readSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readsync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position) and split into lines where you want.

Comment: readSync will read whole file which I don't want.

Comment: Have a closer look at the `offset` and `length` parameters…

Comment: But that is in byte length, its not max lines to read.

Comment: Yes, you have to parse the lines yourself. Or if you want it simple, just use the asynchronous methods available.

Answer (score 0):

Line reader mentions, it is asynchronous but returns a promise. You need to use a synchronous promise handler after the line reader. [Github readme line reader](https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader/blob/master/README.md)

```
var lineReader = require('line-reader');

// read all lines:
lineReader.eachLine('file.txt', function(line) {
  console.log(line);
}).then(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("I'm done!!");
});
```

Comment: Promises are not synchronous.

Comment: They are synchronous to the previous result of a method